# How can I create a string from the parent string from some int position in parent string?

Tags: java, string

Ok let me give an example:

```
    String parentString = "HelloThisIsAString";
    int stringPos = parentString.indexOf("String"); //Will return the position of the text "String" of the parentString.
    String string = //Here the problem arises.
```

In python I do it like this:

```
    string = parentString[stringPos:#to some certain text]
```

How to do it in Java.

Comment: What do you want the final string to have?

Comment: the value which  is the text "String" in the parentString from stringPos.

Comment: substring -- which you could have easily gotten from reading the spec for String.

Comment: I don't get what you mean... Could you rephrase a bit your question (and your example) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substring` method, like this:

```
String parentString = "HelloThisIsAString";
int stringPos = parentString.indexOf("String");
String string = parentString.substring(stringPos, toSomePos);
//                                                   ^^^
//                                                    |
//                                           This is optional
```

Dropping the last parameter gives you a substring from the specific position to the end of the original string.